# Selection algorithms (order statistic) in Java: linear time vs. sorting selector vs. Quickselect

Tags: java, algorithm, array, comparative-review

This post is about computing order statistics: given an array \$A\$ (not necessarily sorted), find the \$k\$th smallest  array component. The entire repository is [here](https://github.com/coderodde/SelectionAlgorithms.java).

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Selector.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection;

/**
 * This interface defines the API for the selection algorithms.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @param <E> the array component type.
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 25, 2022)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 25, 2022)
 */
public sealed interface Selector<E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
        permits LinearTimeSelector, SortingSelector, RandomizedSelector {

    E select(E[] array, int k);
    E select(E[] array, int k, int fromIndex, int toIndex);
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.LinearTimeSelector.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection;

import static com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.checkArray;
import static com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.checkK;
import static com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.checkRangeIndices;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class provides a method for {@code k}th order statistics in worst case
 * linear time.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @param <E> the element type.
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 18, 2022)
 * @since 1.6 (Feb 18, 2022)
 */
public final class LinearTimeSelector<E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
implements Selector<E> {

    private static final int GROUP_LENGTH = 5;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public E select(E[] array, int k, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        checkArray(array);
        checkK(array.length, k);
        checkRangeIndices(fromIndex, toIndex);
        return selectImpl(array, k, fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public E select(E[] array, int k) {
        checkArray(array);
        return select(array, k, 0, array.length);
    }

    private static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> E 
        selectImpl(E[] array, int index, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        E[] medians = getGroupMedians(array, 
                                      fromIndex,
                                      toIndex);

        E pivot;

        if (medians.length <= 5) {
            pivot = medians[medians.length / 2];
        } else {
            pivot = selectImpl(medians, medians.length / 2, 0, medians.length);
        }

        int leftArrayLength = 0;
        int rightArrayLength = 0;

        for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
            E datum = array[i];

            if (datum.compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                leftArrayLength++;
            } else if (datum.compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
                rightArrayLength++;
            }
        }

        E[] leftArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, leftArrayLength);
        E[] rightArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, rightArrayLength);

        for (int i = fromIndex, outputIndex = 0; i < toIndex; i++) {
            E datum = array[i];

            if (datum.compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                leftArray[outputIndex++] = datum;
            }
        }

        for (int i = fromIndex, outputIndex = 0; i < toIndex; i++) {
            E datum = array[i];

            if (datum.compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
                rightArray[outputIndex++] = datum;
            }
        }

        int k = leftArrayLength;

        if (index < k) {
            return selectImpl(leftArray, index, 0, leftArrayLength);
        } else if (index > k) {
            return selectImpl(rightArray, index - k - 1, 0, rightArrayLength);
        } else {
            return pivot;
        }
    }

    private static <E extends Comparable<? super E>>
        E[] getGroupMedians(E[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {

        int arrayLength = toIndex - fromIndex;
        int numberOfGroups = arrayLength / 5 + 
                            (arrayLength % 5 != 0 ? 1 : 0);

        E[] outputArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, numberOfGroups);

        int groupStartIndex  = fromIndex;
        int outputArrayIndex = 0;

        for (int groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < numberOfGroups; groupIndex++) {
            int groupEndIndex = 
                    Math.min(groupStartIndex + GROUP_LENGTH, toIndex);

            Arrays.sort(array, groupStartIndex, groupEndIndex);
            int groupLength = groupEndIndex - groupStartIndex;
            int medianIndex = (groupLength - 1) / 2;

            outputArray[outputArrayIndex++] = array[groupStartIndex +
                                                    medianIndex];
            groupStartIndex = groupEndIndex;
        }

        return outputArray;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.RandomizedSelector.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection;

import static com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.checkArray;
import static com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.checkK;
import static com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.checkRangeIndices;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class implements a randomized selector relying on the ideas of 
 * quicksort.
 * 
 * @param <E> the array component type. Must be {@link Comparable}.
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 26, 2022)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 26, 2022)
 */
public final class RandomizedSelector<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements Selector<E> {

    @Override
    public E select(E[] array, int k) {
        checkArray(array);
        return select(array, k, 0, array.length);
    }

    @Override
    public E select(E[] array, int index, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        checkArray(array);
        checkRangeIndices(fromIndex, toIndex);
        checkK(toIndex - fromIndex, index);

        Random random = new Random();
        return selectImpl(array, index, fromIndex, toIndex, random);
    }

    private E selectImpl(E[] array, 
                         int index, 
                         int fromIndex, 
                         int toIndex,
                         Random random) {
        int rangeLength = toIndex - fromIndex;

        if (rangeLength < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The requested range is non-existent, length = " 
                            + rangeLength);
        }

        if (rangeLength == 1) {
            return array[fromIndex];
        }

        int q = randomizedPartition(array, fromIndex, toIndex, random);

        int k = q - fromIndex;

        if (index == k) {
            return array[q];
        } else if (index < k) {
            return selectImpl(array, index, fromIndex, q, random);
        } else {
            return selectImpl(array, index - k, q, toIndex, random);
        }
    }

    private static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
        int randomizedPartition(E[] array,
                                int fromIndex, 
                                int toIndex,
                                Random random) {

        int i = fromIndex + random.nextInt(toIndex - fromIndex);
        swap(array, i, toIndex - 1);
        return partition(array, fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
        int partition(E[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        E x = array[toIndex - 1];
        int i = fromIndex - 1;

        for (int j = fromIndex; j < toIndex - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j].compareTo(x) <= 0) {
                swap(array, ++i, j);
            }
        }

        swap(array, i + 1, toIndex - 1);
        return i + 1;
    }

    private static <E> void swap(E[] array, int index1, int index2) {
        E tmp = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = tmp;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.SortingSelector.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection;

import static com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.checkArray;
import static com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.checkK;
import static com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.checkRangeIndices;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @param <E> the array component type.
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 25, 2022)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 25, 2022)
 */
public final class SortingSelector<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
        implements Selector<E> {

    @Override
    public E select(E[] array, int k, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        checkArray(array);
        checkRangeIndices(fromIndex, toIndex);
        checkK(toIndex - fromIndex, k);
        Arrays.sort(array, fromIndex, toIndex);
        return array[k + fromIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public E select(E[] array, int k) {
        checkArray(array);
        return select(array, k, 0, array.length);
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class provides common methods for dealing with the order statistics 
 * algorithms.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 14, 2022; Love Edition)
 * @since 1.6 (Feb 14, 2022; Love Edition)
 */
public final class Support {

    public static <E> 
        void checkArrayContainsNoDuplicatesElements(E[] array,
                                                    int fromIndex, 
                                                    int toIndex) {
        Set<E> filter = new HashSet<>();

        for (E element : array) {
            if (filter.contains(element)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "The element [" + element + "] is duplicated.");
            }

            filter.add(element);
        }
    }

    public static <E> void checkArrayContainsNoDuplicatesElements(E[] array) {
        checkArrayContainsNoDuplicatesElements(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    public static Integer[] getArray(Random random, 
                                     int length,
                                     int minimumValue,
                                     int maximumValue) {

        Set<Integer> filter = new HashSet<>();

        while (filter.size() < length) {
            int datum = minimumValue 
                      + random.nextInt(maximumValue - minimumValue + 1);

            filter.add(datum);
        }

        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(filter);
        Collections.<Integer>shuffle(ints, random);

        return ints.toArray(new Integer[length]);
    }

    static <E> void swap(E[] array, int index1, int index2) {
        E tmp = array[index1];
        array[index1] = array[index2];
        array[index2] = tmp;
    }

    static <E> void checkArray(E[] array) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(array, "The input array is null.");

        if (array.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input array is empty.");
        }
    }

    static void checkK(int rangeLength, int k) {
        if (k < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'k' is negative: " + k);
        }

        if (k >= rangeLength) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "'k' is too large: " + k + 
                    "Must be at most " + (rangeLength - 1) + ".");
        }
    }

    static void checkRangeIndices(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (fromIndex < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "frontIndex is negative: " 
                            + fromIndex
                            + ". Must be at least 0.");
        }

        if (toIndex < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "toIndex is negative: " 
                            + toIndex
                            + ". Must be at least 0.");
        }

        if (fromIndex > toIndex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "fromIndex(" + fromIndex + ") > toIndex(" + toIndex + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.AbstractSelectorTest.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection;

import static com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support.getArray;
import java.util.Random;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public abstract class AbstractSelectorTest {

    private static final int MAXIMUM_ARRAY_CAPACITY = 10_011;
    private static final int MINIMUM_ARRAY_CAPACITY = 5_317;
    private static final int MINIMUM_INT = -100_000;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_INT =  100_000;

    private Integer[] array ;
    private final Selector<Integer> selector;

    public AbstractSelectorTest(Selector<Integer> selector) {
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    @Before
    public void methodInit() {
        this.array = new Integer[]{ 4, 1, 5, 2, 3 };
    }

    @Test
    public void testSelect1() {
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(1), selector.select(array, 0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSelect2() {
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(2), selector.select(array, 1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSelect3() {
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(3), selector.select(array, 2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSelect4() {
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(4), selector.select(array, 3));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSelect5() {
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(5), selector.select(array, 4));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSelect13() {
        Integer[] array = new Integer[13];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            assertEquals((Integer) i, selector.select(array, i));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void bruteForceTest() {
        Random random = new Random(1L);
        int length =
                MINIMUM_ARRAY_CAPACITY 
                + random.nextInt(
                        MAXIMUM_ARRAY_CAPACITY - MINIMUM_ARRAY_CAPACITY + 1);

        int index1 = random.nextInt(length);
        int index2 = random.nextInt(length);

        int fromIndex = Math.min(index1, index2);
        int toIndex = Math.max(index1, index2);

        Integer[] array1 = getArray(random, 
                                    length,
                                    MINIMUM_INT,
                                    MAXIMUM_INT);

        Support.checkArrayContainsNoDuplicatesElements(array1);

        Integer[] array2 = array1.clone();

        Selector<Integer> sortingSelector = new SortingSelector<>();
        Selector<Integer> linearTimeSelector = new LinearTimeSelector();

        for (int i = fromIndex, k = 0; i < toIndex; i++, k++) {
            Integer int1 = 
                    sortingSelector.select(
                            array1, 
                            k, 
                            fromIndex, 
                            toIndex);

            Integer int2 = 
                    linearTimeSelector.select(
                            array2, 
                            k, 
                            fromIndex, 
                            toIndex);

            assertEquals(int1, int2);
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.LinearTimeSelectorTest.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection;

public class LinearTimeSelectorTest extends AbstractSelectorTest {

    public LinearTimeSelectorTest() {
        super(new LinearTimeSelector<>());
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.RandomizedSelectorTest.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class RandomizedSelectorTest extends AbstractSelectorTest {

    public RandomizedSelectorTest() {
        super(new RandomizedSelector<>());
    }

    @Test
    public void partition() {
        Integer[] array = { 2, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4 };
        RandomizedSelector.partition(array, 0, array.length);
        assertTrue(Arrays.equals(array, new Integer[] { 
            2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8
        }));
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.SortingSelectorTest.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection;

public class SortingSelectorTest extends AbstractSelectorTest {

    public SortingSelectorTest() {
        super(new SortingSelector<>());
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.SupportTest.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SupportTest {

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void throwOnDuplicateElementInArray() {
        Integer[] array = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, -1, 3 };
        Support.checkArrayContainsNoDuplicatesElements(array);
    }

    @Test
    public void passesOnNoDuplicateElementInArray() {
        Integer[] array = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, -1 };
        Support.checkArrayContainsNoDuplicatesElements(array);
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.benchmark.SelectorBenchmark.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.benchmark;

import com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.LinearTimeSelector;
import com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.RandomizedSelector;
import com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Selector;
import com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.SortingSelector;
import com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Support;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * This class implements the selector algorithm benchmark.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Sep 26, 2022)
 * @since 1.6 (Sep 26, 2022)
 */
public final class SelectorBenchmark {

    private static final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 10_000;
    private static final int FROM_INDEX = 1000;
    private static final int TO_INDEX = ARRAY_LENGTH - 1000;
    private static final int MINIMUM_VALUE = -100_000;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_VALUE =  100_000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random random = new Random(seed);

        System.out.println("seed = " + seed);

        Integer[] array1 =
                Support.getArray(
                        random, 
                        ARRAY_LENGTH, 
                        MINIMUM_VALUE, 
                        MAXIMUM_VALUE);

        Integer[] array2 = array1.clone();
        Integer[] array3 = array1.clone();

        Selector<Integer> selector1 = new SortingSelector<>();
        Selector<Integer> selector2 = new LinearTimeSelector<>();
        Selector<Integer> selector3 = new RandomizedSelector<>();

        List<Integer> results1 = warmup(selector1, 
                                        array1,
                                        FROM_INDEX, 
                                        TO_INDEX);

        List<Integer> results2 = warmup(selector2, 
                                        array2, 
                                        FROM_INDEX, 
                                        TO_INDEX);

        List<Integer> results3 = warmup(selector3, 
                                        array3, 
                                        FROM_INDEX, 
                                        TO_INDEX);

        if (results1.equals(results2) && results2.equals(results3)) {
            System.out.println("Algorithms agreed on warmup.");
        }

        results1 = benchmark(selector1, array1, FROM_INDEX, TO_INDEX);
        results2 = benchmark(selector2, array2, FROM_INDEX, TO_INDEX);
        results3 = benchmark(selector3, array3, FROM_INDEX, TO_INDEX);

        if (results1.equals(results2) && results2.equals(results3)) {
            System.out.println("Algorithms agreed on benchmark.");
        }
    }

    private static List<Integer> warmup(Selector<Integer> selector, 
                                        Integer[] array,
                                        int fromIndex,
                                        int toIndex) {

        return run(selector, array, fromIndex, toIndex, false);
    }

    private static List<Integer> benchmark(Selector<Integer> selector, 
                                           Integer[] array,
                                           int fromIndex,
                                           int toIndex) {

        return run(selector, array, fromIndex, toIndex, true);
    }

    private static List<Integer> run(Selector<Integer> selector, 
                                     Integer[] array,
                                     int fromIndex,
                                     int toIndex,
                                     boolean print) {

        List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>(toIndex - fromIndex);
        long duration = 0L;

        for (int k = 0; k < toIndex - fromIndex; k++) {
            shuffle(array, fromIndex, toIndex);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            results.add(selector.select(array, k, fromIndex, toIndex));

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            duration += endTime - startTime;
        }

        if (print) {
            System.out.println(
                    selector.getClass().getSimpleName()
                            + " in " 
                            + duration
                            + " milliseconds.");
        }

        return results;
    }

    private static <E> void shuffle(E[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<E> list = new ArrayList<>(toIndex - fromIndex);

        for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
            list.add(array[i]);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(list, random);

        for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
            array[i] = list.get(i - fromIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

The typical output on my PC is:

```
seed = 1664257975649
Algorithms agreed on warmup.
SortingSelector in 9708 milliseconds.
LinearTimeSelector in 6910 milliseconds.
RandomizedSelector in 1432 milliseconds.
Algorithms agreed on benchmark.
```

**Critique request**

Is there any way to improve the code?

Comment: Do you *wish to know which solution is best (and why)*? (tag [tag:comparative-review])

Comment: @greybeard Whatever comes to mind will do.

Comment: `Selection.checkArrayContainsNoDuplicatesElements()` ignores the indices passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm no fan of `final` for interfaces and classes, this seems to carry to `sealed`.)

- one alternative to specifying `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>` was to accept a `Comparator`
  - I guess that would have been beside the point of comparing algorithms, and complicating implementation.
- `defines the API for the selection algorithms` is a laudable promise - I don't see `com.github.coderodde.algo.selection.Selector` live up to it:
  • Will the contents of `array` stay unchanged, permuted, some values overwritten with others, or worse?
  • Does *`k`-smallest* refer to [`fromIndex`, `toIndex`) or to all of `array`, with the implication *all elements in [0, `fromIndex`) are smaller*?
- I see three implementations of `select(E[] array, int k)` in terms of `select(array, k, fromIndex, toIndex)` - and three inconsistent instances of parameter checking:
  `Selector` could have provided a `default` implementation.

  I guess this is one of the occasions where I'd prefer an abstract class for being able to provide final methods:

  ```
  public abstract class Selector<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {
      /** @param   array  likely to be permuted
          @return  a smallest element of <code>array</code> from <code>fromIndex</code> 
                   to <code>toIndex</code> (exclusive) such that <code>k</code> 
                   elements in range are no greater than it. */
      protected abstract E permuting(E[] array, int k, int fromIndex, int toIndex);

      /** @param   array  may be permuted
          @return  a smallest element of <code>array</code> from <code>fromIndex</code> 
                   to <code>toIndex</code> (exclusive) such that <code>k</code> 
                   elements in range are no greater than it. */
      public final E select_permuting(E[] array, int k, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
          checkArray(array);
          checkRangeIndices(fromIndex, toIndex);
          if (0 == k)
              return Collections.min(Arrays.asList(array).subList(fromIndex, toIndex));
          if (k == toIndex - 1)
              return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array).subList(fromIndex, toIndex));
          checkK(toIndex - fromIndex, k);
          return permuting(array, k, fromIndex, toIndex);
      }

      /** @param   array  will not be modified
          @return  a smallest element of <code>array</code> from <code>fromIndex</code> 
                   to <code>toIndex</code> (exclusive) such that <code>k</code> 
                   elements in range are no greater than it. */
      public final E select(E[] array, int k, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
          checkArray(array);
          E[] range = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, fromIndex, toIndex);
          return select_permuting(range, k, 0, range.length);
      }

      /** @param   array  will not be modified
          @return  an element of <code>array</code> such that <code>k</code> 
                   elements are smaller than or equal to it. */
      public final E select(E[] array, int k) {
          checkArray(array);
          return select_permuting(array.clone(), k, 0, array.length);
      }
  }
  ```

  (When successfully defining a suitable

  ```
      /** @param   array  will be permuted such that <code>k</code> 
                   elements in range no greater than the 
                   <code>k</code>th are at the beginning of the range
          @return  ???
       */
      protected abstract ??? partition(E[] array, int k, int fromIndex, int toIndex);
  ```

  , I'd add a final implementation of `select_permuting(array, k, fromIndex, toIndex)` using that.)
- `LinearTimeSelector`

  - irritatingly introduces another interpretation of `k` in `selectImpl()`
    (without documenting `index`).
  - creates *a lot* of arrays.
    Once `leftArrayLength` and `rightArrayLength` are known, copy just the appropriate number of elements to an array created at the first partition and passed down from there if not wanting to modify `array`.
- I always found pivot selection in *median-of-five-quickselect* somewhat aloft:
  It should be possible to establish bounds for the other "next level medians", not just the middle one in *median-of-five*.
  If `k` was smaller(greater) than the lower(upper) limit for the 1st or 2nd(last or 4th) median, pick that as the pivot.
  (Hardly much use: for sizeable samples, medians can be expected to be close. Small multisets better be handled differently altogether.)

Comment: 20 to 60 for 2nd, 40 to 80 for 4th median of five? 10 to 50 for 1st, 50 to 90 for last…

Comment: (I don't need to suggest another pivot selection for O(n) quickselect, PICK2 from the almost 50 year old paper looks a lot like my idea.)